# How can I join 2 tables&

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables like this:

```sql
select audi_model from audi
```

```sql
select tesla_model from tesla
```

How can I join them to have one table like this

[image: audi_model tesla_model]

Comment: This is not what a database is for. What you'd have is the entity "cars". audi and tesla are just brands, i.e two values of the entity "brands".  This means you should have a table for the brands and then link the cars to their brands. Your query result makes no sense, because what relates the audi model 1 to the tesla model 1? They are not related, so they should not be in the same row.

Comment: How do you construct this output? I mean how do you decide that t_model_1 goes with model_1 (from the audi_model) column? Give us the description of the tables, and how you decide the correspondence between the rows.

Comment: it's just a simple data output for a (.xlsx) file. These two selects have nothing to do with each other.
I just want to output data from 2 tables to one file by listing their data in 2 columns

Comment: In my opinion a dumb question is a not a bad question, upvoting

Answer (score 1):

This transformation is typically done in the middle-tier or client application rather than in a database query.

You can give the tables each a unique sequential index and then `FULL OUTER JOIN` on that index:

```sql
SELECT audi_model,
       tesla_model
FROM   (SELECT audi_model,
               ROWNUM AS rn
        FROM   audi) a
       FULL OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT tesla_model,
               ROWNUM AS rn
        FROM   tesla) t
       ON (a.rn = t.rn)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE audi (audi_model) AS
SELECT 'model_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'model_2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'model_3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'model_4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'model_5' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE tesla (tesla_model) AS
SELECT 't_model_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 't_model_2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 't_model_3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 't_model_4' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | AUDI_MODEL | TESLA_MODEL |
> | --- | --- |
> | model_1 | t_model_1 |
> | model_2 | t_model_2 |
> | model_3 | t_model_3 |
> | model_4 | t_model_4 |
> | model_5 | *null* |

If you then:

```sql
INSERT INTO tesla(tesla_model)
SELECT 't_model_5' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 't_model_6' FROM DUAL;
```

And run it again, the output is:

> | AUDI_MODEL | TESLA_MODEL |
> | --- | --- |
> | model_1 | t_model_1 |
> | model_2 | t_model_2 |
> | model_3 | t_model_3 |
> | model_4 | t_model_4 |
> | model_5 | t_model_5 |
> | *null* | t_model_6 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=53b0269b5748737463cbe8f9e1da49bc)*

As an aside, you may be better to represent your data as single `models` table with `model` and `brand` columns.